# Is there any characteristics difference indicated by this two symbols ?

Tags: inverter, cmos, symbol

During study , I am encountered with this two Inverter symbols . [image]
Sometimes this two symbols are usedn in same logic circuit. Though they are working as inverter, I'm guessing there must be some charecteristic differences indicated by this two symbols.Or there is no logic to use two different symbols in same circuit.

Is this symbols indicated different kind of inverters or some different physical properties  ?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10785/whats-the-difference-between-an-inverter-with-a-bubble-at-the-input-and-one-wit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no difference in performance between these devices.

The lower one is the one that's more commonly used.

The upper one might be used, for example, if the input comes from a NOR or NAND gate and the person drawing the circuit wants to emphasize that this inverter is intended to turn that into an OR or AND gate (by the principle of combining bubbles).

Comment: That last paragraph is the answer. It's just a matter of emphasizing active vs inactive states and readability of the result. If I had an active-low on the input and an active high on the output, I'd write it like the first one.