# What is this symbol (for an inverter)?

Tags: digital-logic

In Weste and Harris's VLSI text, they use the following symbol for a buffer \$Y = A \$. Why does the second inverter symbol have the inverting bubble in front of the gate? Is there some significance to this? I can't write it off as a mistake since it recurs frequently but, scanning the text (Chapter 1) I can't find anything about it.

The linked question does not explain the convention clearly, nor does it explain why it’s useful.

[image]

Comment: A delay perhaps?

Comment: Does [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10785/whats-the-difference-between-an-inverter-with-a-bubble-at-the-input-and-one-wit) answer your question?

Comment: @GodJihyo Not really to be honest. It’s the same question but I don’t follow from that answer what the convention really is or why it’s useful. See my comment below too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a mistake and it is not a delay.  It is adherence to the letter of old school rules about how to indicate logic polarity.

The bubble indicates whether the input/output is positive-true (no bubble) or negative true (bubble) logic.  For the Y output to be a logic 1, the input must be a logic 0, hence the bubble on the input.  The unlabeled intermediate signal will be a logic 0 when the input is a logic 1, hence the bubble.

Back before more complex logic chips were available, a cpu board was a couple of hundred gate packages, and schematics were full of this type of notation.  For example, a counter's carry bit output might be high in the carry state (no bubble), or low in the carry state (bubble).  Without bubbles, an active-low output could be connected to an active-high input and there would be no indication that this was a design error.

DeMorgan's Theorem codifies how to move back and forth between gate types and bubbles.

The most basic logic structure is an inverter.  Because of this, a non-inverting function such as a buffer is in fact, internally, two inverters in series.  In your example, that is shown by someone who was brought up right, trained by someone who was trained by someone back in the day.

Update:

The most basic combinational logical structures, AND and OR, are defined in terms of positive-true signals in and out.  Of course, the real world has other opinions.  How do you indicate that you want an output signal to be positive-true (high) only when both of the inputs are negative-true (low)?

The part you use for this is a NOR gate, but that symbol does not convey the function of the circuit.  Using an AND gate with bubbles on the inputs does.  For something simple such as a non-inverting buffer this seems like an unnecessary complexity, but the image you posted shows what is actually going on inside the part:  a signal that was positive-true was converted to negative-true, then converted back again.

All of this is about intent.  A schematic tells a story.  It has a language with nouns and verbs, punctuation and syntax.  The primary function of a schematic diagram is to convey the intent of the designer to total strangers in a universal language when the original designer is not around to take questions.  To be successful, that takes discipline.

Side note - one could use a single triangle with no bubbles to show a non-inverting buffer, but that hides the fact that internally the signal is going through two circuit stages, not just one.  This affects propagation delay in things like CPLDs and FPGAs, which is a big deal when a 2 ns difference in signal timing can turn success into failure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don’t completely follow, so if possible I’d like to follow up. Are you saying the convention (assuming active high logic, that is assuming logic 1 corresponds to VDD) is to put a bubble on the input if logic 0 on the input leads to logic 1 on the output (as in the case here) and a bubble on the output if a logic 1 input leads to a logic 0 output? I feel like I’m missing something about why the convention matters or is useful. The linked question does not really help.

Comment: See Update . . .

Comment: *The primary function of a schematic diagram is to convey the intent of the designer to total strangers in a universal language when the original designer is not around to take questions. To be successful, that takes discipline.* I couldn't say it any better than that. This not only takes discipline, but also basic awareness that technical communication is a thing to think about. Many people draw schematics because they saw other people draw schematics, more-or-less, without much thinking about what's actually being done when you draw one.

Comment: Grounds ******always****** point down.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand why this convention is so crucial, but I *think* I understand it. Thank you!

Comment: Just returning here as I scan Chapter 1 again. In terms of the convention, would you say it's correct to say that it holds that "at a given gate, if the output/input is to be 1 (true) then the input/output must be 1/0 depending on if there is no bubble/a bubble"? It is convoluted admittedly, but I am just trying to really convince myself of the "intent", to your point in the update. Is one meant to read from the side of interest (whether output/input) as "if you want a 1 here, *then* you must do *this* at the input/output"?